# Typescript for generic return T<K>

Tags: typescript

How to return generic type for generic.

this is a code occurs error "'K' is not a Generic Type."

```
type Foo<T extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> = {} & Bar<T>
type Bar<T extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> = {
    something: T
}

// I wanna return for Promise<Foo<Bar>> type
async function <T, K> (link): Promise<K<T>>{
    ...
    return fetch(link, req);
}
```

Comment: You can't do this - as there isn't a way in TS to constrain K to a generic type. You might be able to work around it though - do you know anything about K up front?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this in general? Can you provide a use case so maybe there is a better solution.